# str object' has no attribute 'strftime' in Jina2 Template. How can I modify DateTime in Jina2 Template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the following line of code for a jinja2 template.

```
<td>{{ record['CreatedDate'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}</td>
```

The output is meant so that I can reformat the following DateTime:2020-09-26T01:23:29.000+0000

This code results in the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "'str object' has no attribute 'strftime'",
```

EDIT: I solved the issue I was having by creating a function on the server-side. I posted the code below!

Comment: You have `time.time()` object, right? Could you use `datetime` package? Jinjia works well with it.

Comment: If you backtrack to where a value for CreatedData gets put in the record, you'll find that it's a string at that point. To use `strftime`, you'll need it to be a `datetime`.

Comment: @kate-melnykova With the html template there is a way for me to use the Datetime package?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Thank you - My question follow up question is if there is a way to manipulate datetime within the HTML template?

Comment: @MattM, No, not in HTML, in Python. As far as I know, Jijia does not support the `time` package

Comment: @MattM you can certainly write filters that will manipulate a `datetime`. Googling "jinja2 datetime filter" will get you lots of info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this issue:

```
def parse_datetime(row):
    """Get DateTime format and Convert to Date Format
    
    Args:
        row (obj): Row of a dataframe.
    
    Returns:
        Formated Date Value
    """
    str_date = row['CreatedDate']
    if str_date != None:
        salesforce_Datetime_Format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
        # obj_date = datetime.strptime(str_date.split('T')[0], '%Y-%m-%d ')
        obj_date = datetime.strptime(str_date, salesforce_Datetime_Format ) - timedelta(hours=7)
        
        new_date = datetime.strftime(obj_date, "%-m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M %p")
        # print('Created Date: '+ row['CreatedDate'])
        # print('New Date: '+ new_date)
        return new_date
    return ''
```